# Three.js load Multiple obj files one after another

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the obj/mtl loader provided by three.js to load several obj files including mtl. 
Now I need to load multiple objs. But I need to load them one after another. I already used `THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onProgress` to add a "Loading Screen". But how can I check for `loaded === total` within the loop for adding new objs. Or should I use a recursive function?

Hope you can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a callback function that is called when an object is loaded. There you can trigger the next loading step.

```js
var index = 0;
var files = ['file1.obj','file2.obj'];

var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

function loadNextFile() {

  if (index > files.length - 1) return;

  objLoader.load(files[index], function(object) {

    scene.add(object);

    index++;
    loadNextFile();

  });

}

loadNextFile();
```

This basic code needs to be extended to load materials.

Comment: With your help I finally found a way to make it work. I used the callback function. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

@brakebein's answer helped me to get this solution right, so I thought I would chime in with my full code that worked for me (fwiw) - THANKS BRAKEBEIN! :)

```
// Texture and OBJ loader
let OBJfiles = ['love3','rose'];
let _MTLLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader().setPath( 'models/' );

// this function will load the next MTL and OBJ file in the queue
function loadNextMTL () {

    if (index > OBJfiles.length - 1) return;

    _MTLLoader.load( OBJfiles[index]+'.mtl', function ( materials ) {
        materials.preload();
        new THREE.OBJLoader()
            .setMaterials( materials )
            .setPath( 'models/' )
            .load( OBJfiles[index]+'.obj', function ( group ) {
                mesh = group.children[0];
                mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                mesh.position.y = 0.25;
                mesh.scale.set(0.02,0.02,0.02);
                markerRoot[index].add(mesh);

                index++; // incrememnt count and load the next OBJ
                loadNextMTL();

            });
            //, onProgress, onError > These can be used to keep track of the loads
        });

}

loadNextMTL (); // kick off the preloading routine
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check `THREE.DefaultLoadingManager`[.onLoad](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/MTLLoader).
That should do the Job, without trying.