# threejs loading obj one by one

Tags: javascript, three.js

im trying to load OBJ in threejs like this

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setPath(codepenAssetUrl1);
objLoader.load( 'wtc.obj', function ( object ) {    
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            let scale = 0.08;

            let area = new THREE.Box3();
                area.setFromObject( child );
            let yOffset = (area.max.y * scale) / 2;

            child.geometry.scale(scale,scale,scale);
            rocketPoints = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInBufferGeometry(child.geometry, particleCount);
            createVertices(rocketParticles, rocketPoints, yOffset, 2);
        }
    });
});
```

another one is this

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setPath(codepenAssetUrl1);
objLoader.load( 'avap.obj', function ( object ) {   
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            let scale = 0.0021;

            let area = new THREE.Box3();
                area.setFromObject( child );
            let yOffset = (area.max.y * scale) / 2;
            const numberOfParticles1 = 3000000;
            var particleCount1 = numberOfParticles1;


            child.geometry.scale(scale,scale,scale);
            spherePoints = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInBufferGeometry(child.geometry, particleCount1);
            createVertices(sphereParticles, spherePoints, yOffset, 3);
        }
    });
},onProgress);
```

and this is next one

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setPath(codepenAssetUrl1);
objLoader.load( '3.obj', function ( object ) {
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            let scale = 0.2;

            let area = new THREE.Box3();
                area.setFromObject( child );
            let yOffset = (area.max.y * scale) / 2;

            child.geometry.scale(scale,scale,scale);
            spacemanPoints = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInBufferGeometry(child.geometry, particleCount*2);

            createVertices(spacemanParticles, spacemanPoints, yOffset, 3);
        }
    });
});
```

in total i have to load more than 3 obj but right now 3 obj cause browser crashes 
so 
the problem is obj loads everything at once which cause browser to crash.

so how can i load one after another.

Comment: Not an answer, just out of curiousity: where did you find that method `THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInBufferGeometry(child.geometry, particleCount*2)` in the `GeometryUtils"? I tried to find it, but there's no mention about it.

Comment: You could try and use the LoadingManager - https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager
Put your assets in an array (each asset will probably need to be an object so you can determine which logic to run inside the load method), loop through the array whilst calling the `load` method on each asset.

Comment: I'd use a recursive call of `loader.load()`

Comment: @danlong Using of `THREE.LoadingManager()` won't help in this case. It'll load all the assets at once asyncronously.

Comment: @prisoner849 oh yes, that's a good point. Then, just the recursive `loader.load()` call as per your suggestion :)

Comment: Similar question: [Three.js load Multiple obj files one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993833/three-js-load-multiple-obj-files-one-after-another)